# how to print a nested lists line by line seperated by commas

Tags: python

im trying to print this list line by line separated by commas this is what I have so far

```
A = [["1", "2", "3"], ["2", "3", "4"], ["4", "5", "6"]]
for i in A:
    for k in i:
        print(k.join(','))
    print()
```

right now this is printing the lists separately but element by element

this is the expected out put:

```
1,2,3
2,3,4
4,5,6
```

Answer (score 3):

By looping twice, you are getting down to individual elements. For example, the first time through the outer loop, `i` would be `["1", "2", "3"]` and `k` would be `"1"`.

You can just loop over the rows and print the row with the formatting you want:

```
for i in A:
  print(*i, sep=',')
```